# Regex to get data with special characters

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex

I have some data in my table's column `upn`.

Here is a small sample set of this data.

```
Pasquale.Rombolà@it.eurw.domain.net
JuanMaria.RomanGonçalves@eurs.domain.net
Santo.Paternò@it.eurw.domain.net
Peter.Browne@UK.EURW.domain.net
François.ESTIN@fr.eurw.domain.net
Frédéric.Huynh@fr.eurw.domain.net
Frédérique.Psaume@fr.eurw.domain.net
Laura.PiñeiroGomez@eurs.domain.net
Maria.AranzabalSaldaña@eurs.domain.net
Alberto.RubioMuñoz@eurs.domain.net
Peter.Brüggemann@UK.EURW.domain.net
Russel.Peters@CA.domain.net
```

I want to query this table for UPN values where I have some special characters in the UPN. So my query should not return upns such as:

```
Peter.Browne@UK.EURW.domain.net
```

and

```
Russel.Peters@CA.domain.net
```

But returns everything else with special characters such as `[à,ò,ñ,ü ...etc]`

I have tried this query but it doesn't work.

```
Select * from TableName
Where [UPN] like %[a-z,0-9,@,\.,-,A-Z]%
```

It returns everything including those which don't have any special characters.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, I think you'll just need to add a "^" as the first character inside the square brackets.

At present you're saying you want to return all those UPNs where one or more characters is in the list you give (i.e. the "ordinary" characters). The "^" should reverse that and give you all the UPNs where at least one of the characters is not in the list you give.

Update: After testing locally ... Make sure your collation is "Accent Sensitive" (if necessary add "Latin1_General_CI_AS" or similar after your "like" clause.

I found it only worked if rather than "A-Z", I actually typed out the whole alphabet.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add binary collate clause in it. Chose necessary collation as per your data. For given sample data **Latin1_General_BIN** works. 
 Here is the [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180175(v=sql.105).aspx) for collation in sql server.
This snippet worked for me on my machine-

```
create table #t (name varchar(100));

insert into #t values 
('Pasquale.Rombolà@it.eurw.domain.net'),
('JuanMaria.RomanGonçalves@eurs.domain.net'),
('Santo.Paternò@it.eurw.domain.net'),
('Peter.Browne@UK.EURW.domain.net'),
('François.ESTIN@fr.eurw.domain.net'),
('Frédéric.Huynh@fr.eurw.domain.net'),
('Frédérique.Psaume@fr.eurw.domain.net'),
('Laura.PiñeiroGomez@eurs.domain.net'),
('Maria.AranzabalSaldaña@eurs.domain.net'),
('Alberto.RubioMuñoz@eurs.domain.net'),
('Peter.Brüggemann@UK.EURW.domain.net'),
('Russel.Peters@CA.domain.net');

select * from #t where name not like '%[^a-zA-Z0-9@.]%' COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN;
```

**Output-** 
Peter.Browne@UK.EURW.domain.net
Russel.Peters@CA.domain.net

Comment: I think he wants those results excluded

Comment: We just need to flip where clause. select * from #t where name like '%[^a-zA-Z0-9@.]%' COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN; I used NOT clause to reduce number of rows in output to post in reply :)